# getUserMedia mutes the sound while recording current tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, getusermedia

**[Goal]**: To record the sound of a tab and at the same time hear the sound while it's being recorded

**[Means]**: To use `chrome.tabCapture` because it's less invasive than `chrome.desktopCapture` or `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia`. The former provides a better user experience as opposed to the latter which asks for tab selection every time and then intrusively shows the blue rectangle with a status bar and the "Stop Sharing" button

**[Issue]**: Tab sound is muted after getting the stream (recording not necessary, only calling getUserMedia) and can not be unmuted. Is this a bug? How can it be avoided?

**[Technicals]**:

1. Obtain the stream id in a foreground page (popup, options, or iframe pointing to an extension page, injected in the current DOM by a content script) because that's the only place where tabCapture is available

```js
const tabId = ...get current tab id...
chrome.tabCapture.getMediaStreamId({ consumerTabId: tabId }, function(streamId) {
    // send the streamId to the content script
})
```

2. Receive the streamId then use it to start the capture

```js
const options = {
    audio: {
        mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'tab',
            chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
        }
    }
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(options).then((tabStream) => {
    // at this point the sound of the tab becomes muted with no way to unmute it
});
```

3. Just invoking tabCapture will mute the tab. `AudioContext` source connecting to the default destination doesn't do anything for this stream and no error is thrown. If the callback promise from getUserMedia is empty, the sound of the tab comes back on its own in about 20 seconds or so. If MediaRecorder actually uses the stream to record the sound, the sound doesn't come back until recording is stopped. The sound of the tab **is present in the recording**, just muted while recording.

**[Comparison 1]**: Obtaining a MediaStream directly with `chrome.tabCapture.capture` instead of the above mechanism works as intended. The tab sound is muted, but can be reconnected to the speakers using `AudioContext`. The issue with this approach is that chrome.tabCapture.capture can't be started successfully in an injected iframe (always fails with the cryptic "*Error starting tab capture*"), so there's no way to capture the sound. It does work in a popup though, but not really an option given its volatile nature.

**[Comparison 2]**: `chrome.desktopCapture` works in the opposite way. The sound is always present in the tab while recording and can not be muted, not that this poses a problem.

Comment: Check out [this link](https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/?crx=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fchrome-audio-capture%2Fkfokdmfpdnokpmpbjhjbcabgligoelgp%2Frelated) on line 176 in background.js.

Comment: @ojonasplima this doesn't apply in several critical ways. First, this is an MV2 extension. As you already know, you can no longer upload MV2s to the store and MV3 doesn't support tabCapture in service workers. Secondly, to conform to MV3 requirements, you need to access tabCapture in a foreground page, which is an iframe, tab, popup or options page and the only one that is invisible is the content iframe. The content iframe doesn't support tabCapture directly but only getting a stream id, which when passed back to the content script suffers the unmute-able issue.

Comment: Easily reproduce the bug by using the minimal example demo extension I created at https://github.com/Deewde/getUserMedia-mutes-the-tab